# How to get progress of interactive program from ruby?

Tags: ruby, rsync, macruby

I'm trying to create a macruby app that calls a rsync script with the --progress argument, but the way rsync displays its progress is by changing the same line, not adding new lines to its output, so how can I grab this data?

Comment: The problem is rsync writes to the same line, I figured a way around, based on this http://coderrr.wordpress.com/2008/10/21/when-to-use-readpartial-instead-of-read-in-ruby/ which uses IO.popen readpartial to get partial data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rsync lets you change the format of the information being displayed using the `--log-format` option:

```
--log-format=FORMAT
      This allows you to specify exactly what the rsync client outputs to the user on a per-file basis.  The format is a text string containing embedded
      single-character  escape sequences prefixed with a percent (%) character.  For a list of the possible escape characters, see the "log format" set-
      ting in the rsyncd.conf manpage.  (Note that this option does not affect what a daemon logs to its logfile.)

      Specifying this option will mention each file, dir, etc. that gets updated in a significant way (a transferred file, a  recreated  symlink/device,
      or  a touched directory) unless the itemize-changes escape (%i) is included in the string, in which case the logging of names increases to mention
      any item that is changed in any way (as long as the receiving side is at least 2.6.4).  See the --itemize-changes option for a description of  the
      output of "%i".

      The --verbose option implies a format of "%n%L", but you can use --log-format without --verbose if you like, or you can override the format of its
      per-file output using this option.

      Rsync will output the log-format string prior to a file's transfer unless one of the transfer-statistic escapes is requested, in  which  case  the
      logging  is  done at the end of the file's transfer.  When this late logging is in effect and --progress is also specified, rsync will also output
      the name of the file being transferred prior to its progress information (followed, of course, by the log-format output).
```

You should be able to configure it on the fly into something more usable.

Also, you should be able to capture the percent transferred number if you've used `popen3`, and use that to create your own progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

you should use [IO.popen](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M002242) with block notation